# Forcing landscape orientation when phone is upside down

Tags: orientation

When lying on the bed with my head on the pillow, I basically can't use my (mi4) phone: if I hold it upright, it goes to regular portrait mode and it's not aligned with my eyes (my head is on the pillow). If held upside down, regular portrait too. If held horizontally (top & bottom of the phone facing the walls) it switches to landscape, still not aligned with my eyes. In fact, it is entirely incompatible with this body/head position.

How is that possible ? Using a phone in this position is incredibly common yet you just can't ! My Lumia 520 (Windows) understood that the phone upside down means the user is lying on his/her bed, head on pillow, thus switched to landscape, so I could watch YT videos and browse websites in landscape.

Anyway, is there an app or anything to, for example, force the phone to stay in landscape when phone is upside-down ?

Comment: What do you mean by "upside-down"?

Comment: upside-down means with the upper part where the lower part should be; in an inverted position.

Comment: So, what do you want, to have it locked in landscape while the phone is positioned vertically? Your phone rotates 180° (upside down) when the phone is upside-down?

Comment: As I said I want to "force the phone to stay in landscape when phone is upside-down". Yes, currently when phone is upside-down I see normal portrait meaning phone turned its display upside-down in order to "cancel" its upside-down physical position.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what version of android/ROM you ate running there should be an option to lock the orientation. It could be in the quick settings in the notification drawer, or settings > display > orientation.

Comment: Thanks Tyler, yeah but it would be better if the phone could just switch to landscape in upside down position, without anything to do.

Answer (score 0):

I've written an app that can do this. It replaces Android's auto rotation with its own. Get it [here](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=samuelpalmer.sensorautorotation). If you disable the *Allow upside-down screen* option, it should work the way you expect.

Keep in mind, though, that this app is really intended to let you use auto rotation while you're on your side, so you might find that it gets in the way if you don't want that functionality.